# TestFlight App installs but does not show installed in TestFlight App Display (TestFlight shows it at 90% installed)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, testflight

So I have two apps successfully submitted for TestFlight Beta Testing (See image below).

For the first one, installation works as expected. For the second one, the app appears "stalled" at around 90%. Never gets passed what's shown in the image. However, if I return to the home screen the app has installed (no install progress indicators on app icon) and appears to be functioning normally.

I receive no errors within TestFlight and no error logs are produced. TestFlight just never shows the "OPEN" icon for this particular app.

Some other External Testers are also seeing this so it leads me to believe it has something to do with my build and it could be something I can fix. (I do not know if all external users are seeing this issue). Biggest concern is this will happen to some users when the app is released in the App Store and they will end up losing their data.

I have tried deleting and re-installing the app with no success. I have also tried killing the TestFlight app process. "Stopping" the install simply shows "INSTALL" and reselecting gets to what's shown below. Version updates also display the same issue.

Anyone have any ideas on what may be wrong with this particular app?

[image]

Comment: This is TestFlight bug, you can find [more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377170/internal-testflight-build-not-installing-hangs-at-90#comment48466396_29476526).

Comment: @Deny, post an answer and I'll give you the 50 points as this led me to my resolution! I was using a build number of 1.1.009, NOT GOOD (i.e., can't use '0' after '.') I tried 1.1.9 for build number and it now works.

Comment: You already did it :-) I wrote anwer but it was transformed into comment, so never mind.

Comment: Try again, I just deselected my answer. You should be able to post any answer just so I can give you the 50 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved using a build number that does not contain a '0' following a '.'

for example,

```
Build Version: 1.1.002  # no good

Build Version: 1.1.2    # WORKS
```

Answer (score 2):

@kanso already posted the solution. So be aware of using bad app version numbers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ive seen this, and it seems a bug in the test flight app, since the applications seem to install properly as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry, it is a bug by Test Flight. People have registered their complaints. Hopefully, they will fix it soon.