# Cannot install distribution build of iOS app via testflight, iTunes (adhoc), or on AppStore reviewers phones

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I have an app which works fine when building via debug but I cannot install a distribution build via the following:

**1.** Cannot install via [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) internal testing due to this error (in the testflight app):

> unable to download app could not be installed at this time

*I have seen solutions to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821175/testflight-testers-getting-unable-to-download-app-could-not-be-installed-at-thi) but nothing works*

**2.** Cannot install via iTunes (using an AdHoc profile) as the app
installation hangs in the 'Installing..' status

**3.** While in review with the Apple app review team, the app app launches but immediately crashes.

**I have made sure that the following are NOT the problem:**

**a)** I have tested the app in **IPv6** envireonment.

**b)** I have **time-profiled the app** to show that it launches immidiately without 
any thread blocking/delaying (Watchdog). This would not be the problem anyway because the above issues don't even allow the app to install in some cases.

**c)** I have made sure that all the developer/distribution **certificates and provisioning profiles** are in order and that there are no conflicts in my keychain.

**d)** I have tested to see if the problem occurs on a build that is not built with **bitcode**. With or without bitcode i have the same problem.

**e)** I have viewed the contents of the AdHoc provisioning profile to make sure my **device UUID** was there and it is.

**f)** I have deleted **derived data** and **cleaned build** and folders when necessary.

**g)** I have tried to install the app on an **another device**.

I'm not sure what I could be missing here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

This ended up being a bug in Xcode (or the Apple developer portal) that seemed to mess up my provisioning profiles for the app id I was using.

I'm not sure exactly what I did to produce the bug in the first place but the final solution was staring a new project with a new app id and moving all the files from the previous project there.