# I cannot test my app in TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm trying to submit and app to the app store. The first time i tried, it was rejected because this error

> > Guideline 2.3 - Performance
>
> We were unable to install the app on iPhone. The
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a
> way that the app will not install on an iPhone.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
> key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your
> app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device.
> Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are
> required and false if they must not be present on the device.
>
> Resources
>
> Please review the Technical Q&A 1397: Understanding the
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key for information on the
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.
>
> You may also wish to review the dictionary keys table in the
> "Declaring the Required Device Capabilities" section of the App
> Programming Guide for iOS.

So i tried this answer...

> > Various iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch devices use armv7 processors. Setting that value is not what you need to make an iPhone-only app.
>
> Delete that entire "Required device capabilities" entry.
>
> To make an iPhone-only app, simply select "iPhone" for the "Device
> Family" settings (as opposed to iPad or Universal).
>
> And please note that all iPhone-only apps must also work on iPads
> as-is. They will run the 1x/2x iPhone compatibility mode. This means
> your app must also support 3.5" iPhone sizes.

But i'm still getting the error that i got the first time...

[image]

This is my info.plist (notice that my app is just for iPhone)

[image]

So, what can i do???
Thnanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be related:

[Testflight testers getting "unable to download app could not be installed at this time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821175/testflight-testers-getting-unable-to-download-app-could-not-be-installed-at-thi)

I would try uploading another build, and attempt to install it at least once as an internal tester prior to submitting it for beta app review.

If that doesn't work, there are a few other tips in there (i.e. could be a certificate/provisioning profile issue).